# HTML - Move text by window size

Tags: html, css, web, mobile-website

Hey I want to move a text when I resize the window but it goes behind the window.... Does anyone know how to fix something like this?

```css
.DISCORD {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Poppins-Light';
    text-decoration: none;
    top: 3vh;
    left: 208vh;
    font-size: 3vh;
}
```

```html
    <!--DISCORD LINK-->
    <a class="DISCORD" target="_blank" href="https://discord.domain.com/">DISCORD</a>
```

[first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A9TK.jpg)

[other picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snvg5.jpg)

Comment: Please check  your code snippet and make it show something so we can see the problem for ourselves. There is nothing in your code which alters where the text is when the window is resized. Also 208vh is a rather unusual sort of placement - having a horizontal position depend on the vertical height of the window. Is that really what you meant?

Comment: The two pictures are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your pictures look exactly the same, and your code snippet is emtpy.

Did you give `position: relative;` to the parent element?

The reason why your text moves out of the screen is probably because your `left: 208vh;` is to much, try to adjust that property within the devtools of your browser.
Try it maybe with pixel.

It could help if you could post your code into the snippet.

Comment: Hey ^^
I did position: absolute and left 208vh and with px it wount work too :(

Comment: Could you share your code/example in an snippet to be able to analize it better please?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, both images are same. So not clear about the issue. As I understood, you want to see the button all the time at top-left of the page. What you can do is: add left, and top positions with px, rem, etc and make sure that any of its parent elements don't contain position relative.